# How to use sendMessage() from VB-makro to c# Excel-Workbook-Office-AddIn

Tags: c#, vba, visual-studio-2013, excel-addins

Using Excel-2010, Visual-Studio-2013 Professional,

I am trying to send (or post) a message from VisualBasic-makro to a c# Office-AddIn (more precisely a Excel 2010 Workbook Office-AddIn, [not a ThisAdd-In]). How do you do that ?? How would the VisualBasic Code have to look like ??

Following a similar approach to [this link](http://www.greycastle.se/vsto-to-vba-and-back-again/), I can't get the following override to work as stated in the link's solution:

```
protected override object RequestComAddInAutomationService()
```

It seems to me that [the link's](http://www.greycastle.se/vsto-to-vba-and-back-again/) approach only works for a c# Office-AddIn that is an ThisAdd-In instead of a Workbook-AddIn). I choose the following project option in Visual-Studio (under "new-->project-->Visual-c#..."): "Excel 2010 Workbook" Office Add-ins :

[image]

There are so many different AddIn's that are, in my oppinion, quite confusing to follow!

My inital question remains:
How can I send a message from VisualBasic-Makro to this Excel-2010 Workbook ???
How would the Visual-Basic Code have to look like ???

Here is my c# part (inside ThisWorkbook.cs) (not sure if correct at all because of the "protected override issue")...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using stdole;

namespace ExcelConfig
{

    /// <summary>Interface for the COM-object, this is what the VBA actually will see/work against</summary>
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    public interface IMacroMessages : IDispatch
    {
        void SendMessage(string message);
    }

    /// <summary>Implementation of the COM-interface</summary>
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class MacroMessages : IMacroMessages
    {
        public void SendMessage(string message)
        {
            // Our implementation in VSTO
            MessageBox.Show(message);
        }
    }

    public partial class ThisWorkbook
    {

        public static MacroMessages MacroMessages { get; set; }

        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        // Here, the "protected override" did not work as in the ThisAddIn link
        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        public object RequestComAddInAutomationService()
        {
            return MacroMessages ?? (MacroMessages = new MacroMessages());
        }

        private void ThisWorkbook_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void ThisWorkbook_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region VSTO Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisWorkbook_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisWorkbook_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

How does the Visual-Basic Code have to look like to send a message to my Excel-Workbook-AddIn ???

My approach so far in VisualBasic:

```
Sub sendMesssageToActiveWindow()
    Dim addin As COMAddIn
    Dim comObject As Object

    ' Load the VSTO addin
    ' !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    ' Here is where an error occurrs currently
    ' How to solve this ????
    ' !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    Set addin = Application.COMAddIns("ExcelConfig.xlsm")

    ' Fetch the COM object, unfortunatly we´re not able to get any intellisense here as it´s loaded runtime
    Set comObject = addin.Object

    ' Invoke the method
    comObject.SendMessage "This is the message we pass to the method"
End Sub
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: the code you have shown looks like its from the template it self, how much have you coded yourself and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I added the VB-code right in the question above - and also, I added most of the code myself taken from [link](http://www.greycastle.se/vsto-to-vba-and-back-again/)  - please have a look at the VB-code I added in the question above... Unfortunately, the VB-code throws an exception  at `Application.COMAddIns("...")` How would this VB-code have to look like ?? And also, is the above c#-code correct at all??